# Connect to SFTP via CURL

Tags: centos, curl, ftp

```
[user@1070741-VM1 logs]$ curl --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 --ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 -k sftp://ftp.domain.com/db/ --user user:pass
curl: (2) Failure establishing ssh session
```

Im trying to connect to an FTP folder from CentOS 7, the FTP has the following security settings:

[image: FTP Settings]

I can connect with those settings, but i can not replicate from command line, any ideas how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try using bash with inject to marker (assuming you're using rsa keys)

```
#!/bin/bash
sftp {user}@{host} <<EOF
cd {remote_dir}
mget *
EOF
```